# Pairing random items in lists

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to make a program to randomize entries for an event. I have the program working well enough for entering the entries but I'm stuck at randomizing it.

I have 2 lists, let's call one Head and the other one Heel. I have the lists as follows:

- Head: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
- Heel: `[1a, 2a, 3a, 4a, 5a, 6a, 7a, 8a, 9a, 10a]`

I want each item in the Head to have 2 random partners from Heel, but no value from Heel can be matched more than twice at the end of it all. In the final output, each entry should be listed twice and only twice.

Hopefully someone understands and is able to help me, thanks.

Comment: It would be better to show the code where you've tried things out and ask a specific question about it...

Comment: There's no question here. A list of things you want is not a question. What's your *specific question that has an answer?*

Comment: I don't think this is too bad once you understand what the OP is trying to achive, it's just badly worded!

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I need to go take a long bath, I feel so dirty for having this piece of code see the light of day, but something about OP's logic was mezmerizing. Anyway, 3 AM me thinks this should work:

```
var head = new List<char>("abcdef");
var heel = new List<char>("123456");
heel = heel.Concat(heel);

var randomer = new Random();

foreach (var knownItem in head)
{
    var idx1 = randomer.Next(heel.Count);
    var pair1 = heel[idx1];
    heel.RemoveAt(idx1);

    char pair2='\0';            
    while (true)
    {
       var idx2 = randomer.Next(heel.Count);
       pair2 = heel[idx2];
       if (pair2 != pair1)
       {
          heel.RemoveAt(idx2);
          break;
       }
    }

    //DoTheDew
}
```

Next steps for tomorrow: dieharder test the results of this version vs @Arj

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.  Since there's no code to start with, I've done it in pseudocode for now.

1. Create two Lists, each having all of the values in `heel`; call them `heel1` and `heel2`
2. For each element `i` in `head`:

   1. Generate a random number `j` where `0 <= j < heel1.size`. Remove the element at `heel1[j]` - that's your first pairing
   2. Repeat with `heel2` (for a different generated `j`). Remove that element at `heel2[j]` - that's the second pairing
   3. Store `i` along with the two removed values

By the end you will have two numbers for each value in `head`, with no value from heel appearing more than twice.  Since we are removing any used values each time, we don't need to check for your "more than two pairings" rule.